# The app references non public selectors in payload: queryString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm trying to validate the app with xcode but it gives me warning. There are `FacebookSDK`and`AFNetworking` frameworks included.

[image]

How can i remove this warning? Will it affect on reject binary?

Comment: This is not a question...

Comment: @Wain : There's two questions at the bottom: "How can i remove this warning? Will it affect on reject binary?"

Comment: @SandyChapman there wasn't when I added the comment... The question should really also include the code in the section specified by the error if we're going to do anything other than guess about a solution.

Comment: @Wain : Weird. I had assumed it wasn't edited because at the time it said your comment was newer than the post. Must have been a SO caching issue. In any case, these warnings can likely be ignored if the asker does a global search and sees they're not using the value `queryString` in their code. Sometimes the Apple heuristic makes false positives (hence, why it's a warning and not an error).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using non public apple api's. Try of figure out where and remove them. Apple will reject the app if you submit a app that uses private apple api's. If you think it is in Facebook or AFNetworking you could try updating them. Altho I don't think that is the problem if you are not using really old versions of those.